# Xades4j - XML Signature Verification error - SignaturePolicyNotAvailableException

Tags: java, xml, verifyerror, xades4j

I receive XML Invoice with Xades EPES signature and I have to control it.
So I try to do that with Xades4j. I have fixed lot of error But I stuck on the error:

```
errxades4j.verification.SignaturePolicyNotAvailableException: Verification failed for property 'SignaturePolicyIdentifier': signature policy document is not available
    at xades4j.verification.SignaturePolicyVerifier.verify(SignaturePolicyVerifier.java:67)
    at xades4j.verification.SignaturePolicyVerifier.verify(SignaturePolicyVerifier.java:38)
    at xades4j.verification.QualifyingPropertiesVerifierImpl.verifyProperties(QualifyingPropertiesVerifierImpl.java:58)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:202)
```

Java code use to verify signature :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("keystore.jks");
KeyStore trustAnchors = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
trustAnchors.load(fis,"password".toCharArray());
fis.close();

CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(trustAnchors, false);
XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidator);
XadesVerifier v = p.newVerifier();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db =  dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
Document doc = db.parse(is);

Element sigElem = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(Constants.SignatureSpecNS, Constants._TAG_SIGNATURE).item(0);
XAdESVerificationResult r = null;
r = v.verify(sigElem,null);
```

If necessary I can post an extract of kind of XML file I try to verify after anonymization.

Thanks.
I have looked and tried all i have found (on the net, xades4j example, xades4j junit class...) but nothing seems to resolve my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your own policy document provider like this: `p.withPolicyDocumentProvider()`.
And you have to implement your own policy provider which implements the interfaces `SignaturePolicyInfoProvider` and `SignaturePolicyDocumentProvider`. (at least I did it that way)

**Edit to your comment:**

You need to implement `SignaturePolicyInfoProvider.getSignaturePolicyDocumentStream()`, which returns an `InputStream`. This can be a `FileInputStream`

**Example**:

```
public class FilebasedSignaturePolicyProvider implements  SignaturePolicyDocumentProvider {

    @Override
    public InputStream getSignaturePolicyDocumentStream(ObjectIdentifier sigPolicyId) {
        String oid = sigPolicyId.getIdentifier();

        try {
            return new FileInputStream("directory-to-my-policy-files/" + oid);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes your right for EPES it seems we need to set PolicyDocumentProvider. Unfortunately I don't understand how to set up my own policy provider. I am looking to the xades4j example XadesVerifierImplTest... and I don't find any good documentation on this.